# Passing Quotation Number to Email

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

I have a problem on passing the current displayed quotation number as to be sent out to the email. Which means when handleEmailPress, the default mail application will open with the subject content as the Quotation Number and it's QuotationNumber Value to be displayed

this is my detail.controller.js

```
handleEmailPress: function (oEvent) {

    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("model/mock.json");
var QN = oModel.getData().QuotationNumber;
    //sap.m.URLHelper.triggerEmail(this._getVal(evt), "Info Request")
    sap.m.URLHelper.triggerEmail( "test111@gmail.com", "hello", "QuotationNumber" + QN  )
        sap.m.MessageToast.show("E-Mail has been sent");
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem here. You code works fine: http://jsbin.com/vutozixova/1/edit?html,output   Maybe the problem is in getting the correct path to the `QuotationNumber` property?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Yes probably thats the error. How do i do get the correct path of the QuotationNumber property. The data is on JSON model. I'm sorry i'm quite new to this.

Comment: I can't help you if I don't see the file itself.

Comment: put the data present in mock.json file..so that we can know the structure of your data..